# Script command without output

Tags: scripting

Is there something similar to `script` that records **ONLY** the commands and not any output from them to a file?

Comment: Isn't your shell's history sufficient for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
history
```

It shows you what your shell last did. Every command. No output. It is editable.